# How to add package path for python2 and python3 separatly?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

I know that set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` works. However, it works for both python2 and python3. How could I set a path only for python3?

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want my python3 import packages from the path `my/python3/path`, but forbidden my python2 import from it.

Comment: Try looking into python's `sys.path`.

Comment: Edit the `sys.path` in the interactive shell of course works. I am looking for a   better solution to make it work automatically.